# monitoring elipselink cache L2,L1

Tags: java, jpa, caching, eclipselink

Is there a tool or a programmatic method to monitor the level one,two cache of eclipse link. my goal is to know the number of entity cached for a certain class.
here some links i found but they are not enough:

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/performance002.htm
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Monitoring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA doesn't specify such capabilities, however you can do it with EclipseLink internals e.g.:

### L1 (transactional cache, persistence context)

```java
import org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaEntityManager;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl;
...
JpaEntityManager jem = em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class);
UnitOfWorkImpl ouw = jem.unwrap(UnitOfWorkImpl.class);
...
long count = countCachedEntitiesL1(clazz);
```

and the corresponding method:

```java
// Java 7
public long countCachedEntitiesL1(Class clazz) {
    long count = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entity : ouw.getCloneMapping().entrySet()) {
        if (entity.getKey().getClass().equals(clazz)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

```java
// Java 8
public long countCachedEntitiesL1(Class clazz) {
    return ouw.getCloneMapping().keySet().stream()
        .filter(entity -> entity.getClass().equals(clazz))
        .count();
}
```

### L2 (shared cache)

```java
import org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaEntityManager;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.IdentityMapAccessor;
...
JpaEntityManager jem = em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class);
ServerSession ss = jem.unwrap(ServerSession.class);
IdentityMapAccessor ima = (IdentityMapAccessor) ss.getIdentityMapAccessor();
...
int count = countCachedEntitiesL2(clazz);
```

and the corresponding method:

```java
public int countCachedEntitiesL2(Class clazz) {
    return ima.getIdentityMap(clazz).getSize();
}
```

Comment: ouw.getCloneMapping always returns empty map. is there ana further configuration needed. note that all configuration related to cache is keeped default which indicate cache working.

Comment: Just to clarify - are we talking about persistence context or shared cache?

Comment: sorry i meant shared cache , question edited. i will try to surf through classes related to Session in order to find the entities, if there is a way please inform me thank you @wypieprz

Comment: please @wypieprz reupdate the answer , ServerSession must be unwraped instead of unitofwork in order to access L2 shared cache. thanks again

Comment: Hmm, do you mean something like this: `((org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.IdentityMapAccessor)jem.unwrap(ServerSession.class).getIdentityMapAccessor()).getIdentityMap(Client.class).getSize()` ?